# Argument of type “Location” is not assignable to parameter of type “BackgroundGeoLocationEvents”

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4

It looks like I can't define the "location" event for the [Background Geolocation plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation).

I tried:

- Remove node_modules folder and npm install
- Use the ngx import
- Verified that the BackgroundGeolocationEvents is defined (is its: *export declare enum BackgroundGeolocationLocationProvider*)
- Using "location" and 'location'

[image]

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it might be a mistake in the docs then?

Try just playing the game it wants you to play.

Instead of:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.on("location")...
```

Use:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location)...
```

You might need to add an import at the top as well to import `BackgroundGeolocationEvents` in.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: fyi I did a pull request to update the docs so this shouldnt trip anyone else up once it gets merged :)